# How to import Date and Time variable.

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this.

```
sd<-structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 3L), .Label = c("9/1/2014 8:00", 
"9/20/2014 14:06", "9/21/2014 15:57", "9/24/2014 14:13", "9/26/2014 15:00", 
"9/26/2014 9:04", "9/28/2014 14:02"), class = "factor"), User_ID = c(4.56789e+14, 
9.45678e+14, 3.45678e+14, 4.56789e+14, 4.56789e+14, 9.45678e+14, 
9.45678e+14)), .Names = c("DateTime", "User_ID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

When I try to import this type of data into R using fread, it is treating DateTime variable as character. How can I overcome this Issue...Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be

```
library(lubridate)
mdy_hm(as.character(sd$DateTime))
# [1] "2014-09-26 15:00:00 UTC" "2014-09-24 14:13:00 UTC"
# [3] "2014-09-01 08:00:00 UTC" "2014-09-20 14:06:00 UTC"
# [5] "2014-09-26 09:04:00 UTC" "2014-09-28 14:02:00 UTC"
# [7] "2014-09-21 15:57:00 UTC"
```

### Edit

```
format(mdy_hm(as.character(sd$DateTime)), "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: I need output in mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss format only. I dont want UTC